# concatenate array to javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have variable which has multi-line string and I want to put some data from an array in the middle of the string. How do I do that?

```
var a = [1,2,3,4]
var b = `<div>
           //array value here
           <span>1</span>
           <span>2</span>
           ...
         </div>`
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: `<span>${a[0]}</span>` and so on.

Comment: That really depends on what defines _"the middle"_ of the string. Is it always HTML? Is it always the _same_ HTML? Do you always want to insert the value(s) as the first child of the root element?

Comment: What **exactly** does the `b` string look like **before** you manipulate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put expressions in the template literal:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = `<div>
             //array value here
             <span>${a[0]}</span>
             <span>${a[1]}</span>
             ...
           </div>`;
         
console.log(b);
```

Or even:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = `<div>
             //array value here
             ${a.reduce((acc, v) => acc += `<span>${v}</span>`, '')}
           </div>`;
         
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Well, I don't know the length of the array upfront.